# Sencha vs Wavemaker

Tags: javascript, extjs, vmware, sencha-architect

I'm trying to decide between Sencha Architect 2 and Wavemaker. They both seem very similar. Of course Wavemaker is completely open source, and Sencha is only partially open source. For this reason I'm leaning towards Wavemaker, but given the learning curve with either, I'd hate to find myself with less options later on, just because I tried to save some money. Here are my main concerns.

1- I want to be able to sell my application without giving away my source code.

2- Productivity of course is paramount. Are they both about the same?

3- Database development tools.

4- Easy of deployment and hosting options.

Opinions either way are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a good fit for StackOverflow as it requests subjective opinion or debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't make much sense to me. Are you comparing just the IDE-s?

Anyway, your options look like very different things. One is primarily a front-end framework and another one a back-end framework. One produces Java apps, another one JavaScript. Maybe you should compare Wavemaker against Ext GWT instead, which is Java-based.

Given your point 3, your choice should be straight-forward as there are no database development tools in any of those Sencha front-end development tools that you seem to be referring to. There might be something in Ext GWT, but I'm not at all familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks-- these are very good points I was unaware of. This is exactly the kind of perspective I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

wavemaker is for me best tool for now..

1.on javascript can use some tools for obfuscate code
2.WYSIWYG..visual tool with cool ajax widgets drag and drop and offcourse all free
3.have is model part for can create your db
4.cloudfoundry

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure: I work for VMware on WaveMaker.

I felt compelled to correct a few things from Rene’s post.  WaveMaker is not strictly a backend framework.  WaveMaker is a visual, drag-and-drop development tool.  Applications created with WaveMaker contain a backend framework (Java, Spring) and a frontend framework (JavaScript, Dojo).  Developers enhance their UI by writing JavaScript code.

The comparison to GWT implies that UI development in WaveMaker is done using Java.  Although Java is part of the WaveMaker framework, developers do not use Java code to enhance UI functionality.  The back-end code is Java, which is used to access databases and other backend services.  In most cases WaveMaker developers do not need to modify the Java code.  Since WaveMaker produces standard Java/Spring applications it’s easy for a Java developer to extend the backend functionality.

Comment: Thanks for input. I don't really know a thing about WaveMaker - I just posted what I figured out through the website.

Comment: I think this should be a comment on Rene's answer if it is correcting that answer. This doesn't attempt to answer the question.